# Problemas com a criação de novos projetos Java no NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, java-8, jdk

[image: Opões de Novo Projeto no Netbeans]

Nas opções para criação de novo projeto java não aparece a opção 'Java' propriamente dita.
A primeira opção é **Java Whith Maven** como podem ver.

[image: Opções para Nova Aplicação Java]

Dentre as opções disponiveis ou selecionar **Java Whith Maven** não está disponivel a caixa de seleção para criação da classe principal.

Ja verifiquei e o java esta instalado em minha maquina! Inclusive a variavel JAVA_HOME está configurada.

Conhece alguma solução para esse problema??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente o Netbeans não tem essa opção de projeto "básico" que já cria uma classe principal (com o método main).

Na segunda opção da sua segunda imagem será criada uma estrutura de projeto com um pacote padrão. Então, você poderá criar suas classes dentro do pacote e uma delas pode ser sua classe principal. Faça como a seguir:

[image: Menu para criação de classes]

Em seguida escolha o tipo de template de classe que você quer, no seu caso, Java Main Class:

[image: Seleção do tipo de classe]

Clique o botão "Next" e siga as instruções.

Answer (score 0):

Diferente do que o colega respondeu, o NetBeans cria sim um projeto com a classe e método main prontos.

Basta clicar: **Novo Projeto/Java with Ant/Java Application**

Pronto! Já tem seu projeto com a classe (NomeDoProjeto) já criada como inicializadora e método main dentro dela prontos.

Veja o exemplo:
[Criar Novo Projeto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skxGw.png)
[Selecionar Java com Ant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stcRh.png)
[Lembre-se de verificar ou editar a caixa de criação da classe main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnpaG.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).